# Format text color based on background color of other cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm trying to make things easier for other people using an Excel file.

I need to color the concatenated result according to what color is in the original cells.

For example, as in the original cells cells have colors, in the concatenated result it should also apply: `pe` should be gray, `pd` blue, `email` orange... and so on... But in the concatenate string below all text is black.

Is this possible?

**The goal is to make it easier to tell from which cell comes the each part of the concatenated result.**

[image]

[image]

**Edit 1:** Yes, formula is in H7.

[image]

However, running that code does not show any result?

[image]

[image]

**Edit 2:**

So code, creates a copy of concataned string, but still missing the colors.

[image]

Comment: The result of a formula string does not accept many colors of the resulted characters. Then, if you transform formula it in value/text you loose the precedents used in formula. This "easier" is relative. Must they interpret a formula and its result should become more eloquent by this characters coloring? As I said, it is not possible in a string retuned by a formula... If you better explain which is the goal, we will maybe find a VBA way to do it keeping the relevance... Do you want/need that only for `CONCATENATE` formula?

Comment: @FaneDuru the result comes from different cells... which are dropdown lists... I'd like the end user to know from whart cells comes each part of the concatenated result....

Comment: I asked you if your desire is limited to `CONCATENATE` function...  Then, since the result of the concatenated cells value **cannot be colored per each character** I had in mind some code to copy in the next column the result as value, which can be colored per character, extracting the precedents from the formula...

Comment: @FaneDuru no, it's ok if we copy the concatanated result to other cell.

Comment: Is it possible to have identic strings in the concatenated cells? I mean, the same string/word to be more than once in the concatenated string?

Comment: @FaneDuru yes, none is a value that can be repeated.

Comment: Then, test the solution I posted and send some feedback.

Comment: What's the reason for the colours in the other cells? Is it done manually or is it the result of a conditional formatting? In case of the latter, you can use the condition of that conditional formatting in order to write a new conditional formatting rule.

Comment: @Dominique it's done manually, buy I guess I can create a condition that says if in A2 be red, if B2 be blue?

Comment: @Dominique I am afraid you missed a little the point...  It looks that he wants coloring differently characters of a string which is the result of a formula... Each word from the string to have the color of the cell where from it is taken. Or I am the one missing the point...

Comment: @FaneDuru you're right...

Comment: If I am right, what are you expecting from my code if all used strings have the same Font color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, test the next solution. It uses `Worksheet_Change` event and assumes that the formula is in "H7" (looking to the pictore you show...). When any of cells in the range "H5:P5" is changed, automatically the formula result is copied below the cell having the formula (in "H8") and string characters are colored as the cells where they have been taken for concatenation.

Please, copy the next code in the sheet code module where the formula exists (right click on the sheet name and choose `View Code`):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
      If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("H5:P5")) Is Nothing Then
            Dim aC As Range, rngCol As Range, rngPr As Range, c As Range, strCell As String, startCh As Long
            Set aC = Me.Range("H7")
            Application.EnableEvents = False
                If aC.HasFormula Then
                     Set rngCol = aC.Offset(1)
                     strCell = aC.value: rngCol = strCell
                     Set rngPr = aC.Precedents
                     For Each c In rngPr.cells
                             startCh = InStr(1, strCell, c.value)
                             rngCol.Characters(startCh, Len(c.value)).Font.Color = c.Font.Color
                     Next c
                   End If
            Application.EnableEvents = True
     End If
End Sub
```

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

I would like to also mention that `Precedents` are returned only for the used cells in formula **but only the range(s) from the respective worksheet. I mean, if in concatenation are involved ranges from different sheets, they will not be returned in the `Precedents` range...

**Edited**:

Please, check the next version, which will color each string according to the cel where it has been taken from, even if it has been processed for the previous cells:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
      Dim rngFormula As Range: Set rngFormula = Me.Range("H5:P5")
      If Not Intersect(Target, rngFormula) Is Nothing Then
            Dim aC As Range, rngCol As Range, rngPr As Range, c As Range, strCell As String, startCh As Long
            Dim firstCh: firstCh = 1 'to start searching after the word has been found!
            ReDim arrUsed(rngFormula.cells.count - 1)
            Set aC = Me.Range("H7")
            Application.EnableEvents = False
                If aC.HasFormula Then
                     Set rngCol = aC.Offset(1)
                     strCell = aC.value: rngCol = strCell
                     Set rngPr = aC.Precedents
                     For Each c In rngPr.cells
                             startCh = InStr(firstCh, strCell, c.value)
                             rngCol.Characters(startCh, Len(c.value)).Font.Color = c.Font.Color
                             firstCh = startCh + Len(c.value)
                     Next c
                   End If
            Application.EnableEvents = True
     End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @Omar Gonzales Your formula was/is in "H7" but **in your question it used to reference cells in range "H5:P5"**! As I clearly stated above: **"When any of cells in the range "H5:P5" is changed..."** the event is triggered only for **changes in the respective range**... So, there are two alternatives: 1. To change the code replacing `Intersect(Target, Me.Range("H5:P5"))` with `Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A7:F7"))` or 2. place the range to feed the formula where you show that it should be ("H5:P5")...Then, you do not have to transform the code in a named macro. It runs automatically...

Comment: @Omar Gonzales Is what I tried suggesting above clear enough?

Comment: Please, see edit 2.

Comment: @Omar Gonzales I cannot see anything changed in this "edit 2"... **Can't you explain in words what problem you faced**? Did you understood what I said in my first comment? It looks you don't, if nothing has been changed... If you do not understand something, please ask for clarifications. Only now the answer has been updated and I could see a new picture. Have you TeamViewer or AnyDesk installed? I cannot understand what happens if I cannot see your case...

Comment: @Omar Gonzales In fact, I am looking now to the picture and all involved cells have their font black. What are you expecting from the code? Please **color each cell with a different font color** and see what's happening... Do you want having more than one background color **in a cell**? This is not possible in Excel! I said in my answer: **string characters are colored as the cells where they have been taken for concatenation**...

Comment: Got you! You take the text color, not the background color. I was expecting you to take the bracground color... as for example if I have a dark bg cell with white text... the code will use white in H8... which will be not visible at all.

Comment: @Omar Gonzales Let us settle some things about Excel: 1. **In an excel cell only a interior color is possible**! 2. The text characters of a string returned by a formula **can have a single color**. 3. The string characters from a cell can be colored individually, **but only if the string in discussion is not produced by a formula**. So, if you have white font color change it or place in the cell where the formula will be transformed in string an **interior color (background, how you name it) to allow seeing of all font colors**... These are the single choices to link somehow the colors...

Comment: May we have a call using Teamviewer: 741 978 260. How can I send you the pass? Any email?

Comment: @Omar Gonzales I have a mail account but it is useless in these circumstances, I am afraid, **I cannot do anything from what Excel not allows**. I tried clearly explaining above what is possible and what is not. What do you want showing if I will connect to your computer and it cannot be said in words, in a comment?

Comment: I tried to expand the range to: `"H5:Q5"` but after running it, it still don't capture the text in Q5.  Howcome?

Comment: Please, use my personal mail to send the password: ivangu@yahoo.com. And open a Notepad window to communicate after connection...

Comment: @Omar Gonzales Should I still wait the password? It is late in my country and I cannot wait too much...

Comment: Sent like 15 min ago... please, confir,m.

Comment: @Omar Gonzales not received anything... Place it here, I will confirm I copied and you delete your comment, please.

Comment: @Omar Gonzales OK. Delete your comment...

Comment: @Omar Gonzales I will try connecting again. I am not sure I understood what you want...

Comment: Went for some water... I'll be around here just in case.

Comment: @Omar Gonzales No need, I already adapted the code. Do you want me connecting and explaining what was it about, or only post it here?

Comment: just post it please, we can discuss it later or tomorrow. ty for your help

Comment: @Omar Gonzales OK. Edited and placed the second version. I declared a new variable to keep the start of the `InStr` function which to be adapted after each case... Please, copy it instead existing and confirm that it works as it should.

Comment: @Omar Gonzales What do you mean? I will connect again now... Please, copy the code I posted recently to work on it. If not, I will recreate it in your computer...